# Find out if last caracter is a letter or a number

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet.
Column A, I have different values :

```
A6  : 1520 A7  : 9500 A8  : 9500a A9  : 12450 A10 : 13425 A11 : 13425a
A12 : 13425b
```

(those numbers are files numbers I've generated with the help of another vba macro using advanced filters from a database but that's not the point here.)

What I'd like to do is count the number of different file numbers listed. 
For me `13425`, `13425a` and `13425b` are from 1 file only.

So in this previous example, I'd like to get the following number of different files: 4 (`1250`, `9500`, `12450` and `13425`)

So I've tried different things :

```
    Dim L As Integer ' numéro de la dernière ligne
    Dim I As Integer ' compteur pour itération
    Dim K As String  ' dernier caractère de la case en partant de la droite
    Dim N As Integer ' compteur N

    L = Sheets("Stats").Range("a165536").End(xlUp).Row 'Dernière ligne utilisée

    Range("O1") = L

    N = 0 'initilisation du compteur

    For I = 6 To L
         K = Right(Range("A" & I), 1)
      If IsError(K * 1) = False Then
         N = N + 1
         Else
         N = N
      End If
    Next I
Range("O2") = N
```

But `IsError(K*1)` doesn't work, I have an error.

In MS Excel we can use the following function: `=CODE(RIGHT(A6,1))`.
If the value is `>=48 AND <=57` I know the last caracter is a NUMBER and NOT a letter. But I think this function doesn't exist in VBA ?

SO that's the 2 things I've tried to solve my problem but I didn't manage to find out a solution yet.

Comment: `IsNumeric(Right(A6,1))`

Comment: Please not that *"doesn't work, I have an error."* is no valid error description and completly meaningless. If you get errors you need to tell the error message of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question and question only:

- To find out whether a character *(or a set of characters)* is a number, we can use the [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) function.
- And to get the last character out of a string we can use the [`Right()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function) function.

I've linked to both function's documentation, so do absolutely take a gander!
Your custom function could look something like this:

```
Public Function is_last_num(ByVal strng as String) As Boolean
    is_last_num = IsNumeric(Right(strng, 1))
End Function
```

If you're trying to count unique files based on the number then just use what @RonRosenfeld suggested

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

If your goal is

- to count the number of unique files, and
- the files are defined by the numeric beginning of the full file name,
- Then you can make use of the `Val` function, which will ignore any trailing non-numeric characters.

For example (using a Dictionary to generate the count):

```
Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each myCell In myRange
    Key = Val(C)
    If Not D.Exists(Key) Then D.Add Key, C.Value
Next C
uniqueFiles = D.Count
```